# Publishing from Power BI Desktop always replaces the datasets

Tags: powerbi

If I update the modelling in Power BI Desktop and then publish, I get the following message:
"You already have a dataset named 'xxxxx' in Power BI. Do you want to replace the existing dataset with this one?"

How do I get it to update rather than replace the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

There is no update option. You can only replace, or, if you want to keep the existing dataset, rename the one you are trying to publish so it is unique in the workspace you are publishing to.

A dataset is a query against a source system and, if you are not in direct/live query mode, the associated data. The report you are publishing requires the dataset it is sourced from. The dataset is not separable from the report.

Even if there were no changes between the old dataset and the new dataset (i.e. you just made a cosmetic change to the report), PowerBI.com would have no way of knowing that unless it uploaded the new dataset and compared it to the old dataset. That would take so much longer than a replacement that I'm not sure what the value would be.

*Sidenote: if you're looking to do an incremental update (e.g. only load new rows, and not re-upload existing rows), Power BI doesn't support this yet, but there is an idea you can vote on to get this feature added: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7288623-incremental-data-loads. However, you specifically asked about publishing the report, so I doubt this is what you are looking for.*